# How to create an oauth_signature when some parameters are in the content body in XML

Tags: rest, oauth, restful-authentication

I am building an REST-ful API and I want to implement 2-legged authentication with OAuth. I feel I have a good grasp of the fundamentals, i.e. constructing the oauth_signature based on the request parameters as mentioned here http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#rfc.section.9.1.1 and the use of a nonce and a timestamp.

However if you are doing POST and the body content is XML which contains your parameters what is the best practice for encoding those into your oauth_signature.

For example if I have an end point of http://burger.me/order/ with an accepted method of POST, and the content body is as follows:-

```
<order>
    <item name="Big Mac" count="1" />
    <item name="Whopper" count="2" />
    <item name="Zinger Tower" count="1" />
</order>
```

How does that affect the construction of the oauth_signature? Do I just append the entire xml string or ignore it? I am not sure of the accepted best practice in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either choose to not sign the body (if you're providing over SSL you could probably skip it). Or you can choose to use the `oauth_body_hash` extension to the OAuth Spec.

Documentation here: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/spec/ext/body_hash/1.0/drafts/4/spec.html

Comment: Thanks so much @Jon that is a total God send.